# Data-mining related forums

Tags: data-mining, forums

Which forums you are using for data mining questions? SO is mainly intended for programming, not for DM questions.

Comment: This should probably be moved to Meta or closed. Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: Go to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, [metaoptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa) has some questions on this area.

Comment: And http://www.quora.com contains a lot of stuff related to data mining and machine learning.

Comment: Unfortunately, http://metaoptimize.com/qa doesn't exist anymore

Comment: True, so sorry for this.

Answer (score 7):

I can suggest [KDnuggets](http://www.kdnuggets.com/forums); it is a site focused on data mining and analytics.

(Note: I am an  editor at KDnuggets.)

Comment: Hello Dr. Piatetsky-Shapiro - Kudos and welcome to SO... I know about your site's forum, it's good.

Comment: I know this is an old answer but that forum is full of ads and the actually forum space is tiny on the screen. Maybe one gets good answers there but the website itself is terrible even with ad-blocker.

Comment: Unfortunately, "KDnuggets Forums have been discontinued" (http://www.kdnuggets.com/phpBB/)

Answer (score 6):

Check out [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) Although it's still in beta, there are some nice resources there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what software package you're using but Microsoft has data mining related threads at its MSDN Forum site. Check out [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatamining/threads) link.

Answer (score 2):

You can check my **[data mining forum](http://forum.ai-directory.com/list.php?5)**. It is a small forum but it is alive and there is some people answering questions.